# Google analytics conflicting with JQuery code

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am having an issue where Google analytics is conflicting with my code. The system I am working on loads Google analytics as the first script. This cant be changed, so i need to find a way out of this conflict without re-ordering the scripts.

The code is here. http://jsfiddle.net/2j6Zd/

When removing

```
    $("#slide-right").pageSlide({
        width: "210px",
        direction: "right"
    });
```

It works. So somehow I need to call this differently or soemthing else.

Anyone able to help please?

Comment: I can't see how it's possible for Google Analytics to interfere with jQuery. What specific error do you get in the console? Have you included the js file for the pageSlide plugin?

Comment: From google Chrome inspector i get.  "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Comment: And as for the downvote and minus rep. Please..... so damn petty. This is a legit issue. When i remove the ga.js call, my code executes. When i return the ga.js call the page doesnt load(Transferring data from www.google-analytics.com is all that shows.). So somehow it has something to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution. It was line
$("body").contents().wrapAll(psBodyWrap);

This was wrapping the  _gaq snippet inside as well. So it was firing twice.

The solution was.

$("body").contents().not("footer").wrapAll(psBodyWrap);.

The _gaq snippet was located in the footer. So excluding it from the wrap allowed everything to execute correctly. This points to it being directly related to google analytics code. It might not have been a code conflict, but a conflict none the less.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something is wrong with the way you've pasted/modified your _gaq snippet.

Comment: The  _gaq snippet is correct. The system has been fine for years now with that code. I am modifying the sites for responsive design, so introducing new scripts in. It is the new script(jsfiddle link) that is causing the issues now.